# NSString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfRegex

Tags: objective-c, regex, ios, nsstring

I saw a lot of usages of this method: stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfRegex on NSString on SO.  But I got a waring that said this instance method is not found and at running time crashing with a "unrecognized selector sent to.."

Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That method is an extension provided by [RegExKitLite](http://regexkit.sourceforge.net/RegexKitLite/).

Comment: I ended up using another solution for my need.  But your answer was right.

Comment: user523234, can you write here your another solution?

Answer (score 1):

I've never seen that method, but you can use this one to achieve regular expression manipulation:

```
/* Replace all occurrences of the target string in the specified range with replacement. Specified compare options are used for matching target. If NSRegularExpressionSearch is specified, the replacement is treated as a template, as in the corresponding NSRegularExpression methods, and no other options can apply except NSCaseInsensitiveSearch and NSAnchoredSearch.
*/
- (NSString *)stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:(NSString *)target withString:(NSString *)replacement options:(NSStringCompareOptions)options range:(NSRange)searchRange NS_AVAILABLE(10_5, 2_0);
```

Sorry about the formatting restrictions forcing it onto two lines, check out NSString.h for this code